# Initialise Data in SQLite from string resource

Tags: android, sqlite

i'm trying to initalise my sqlite database with some data (here: categories). I learned, that the right place to do this, is the onCreate method of my DatabaseHandler.

Unfortunately i'm not able to get the String resources out of my strings.xml there. I guess the SQLiteOpenDataHelper doesn't contain any resource methods:

```
   values.put(PAINKILLER_CAT_NAME, R.string.cat2);
   db.insert(TABLE_PAINKILLER_CAT, null, values);
```

This only stores the ressourceid (like 2139123012) as a String.

```
getString();
```

and

```
getResources().getString();
```

are no valid methods within my DataBaseHandler.

Is there only a workaround (like setting up the categories from my firststart-activity) or can i use the String-Ressources within my DataBaseHandler?

Comment: So pass in a context and use that...?

Comment: So, where should i pass/use that?
My DatabaseHandler:  
`public DatabaseHandler(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }` has this context. But how can i use it?

Comment: See the example in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to retain the context passed into the constructor to access resources:

```
package com.comply365.android.myMobile365.util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MySQLiteDatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context mContext;

    public MySQLiteDatabaseHandler( Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super( context, name, factory, version );
        mContext = context;
    }

    public MySQLiteDatabaseHandler( Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler ) {
        super( context, name, factory, version, errorHandler );
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String theString = mContext.getString( R.string.theString );
        ....
    }

    ....    

}
```

Also, if you have multiple categories you would like to add, make sure you use String arrays, like so:

```
<resources>
    <string-array
        name="categories">
        <item>Category 1</item>
        <item>Category Two</item>
        <item>Category C</item>
        <item>Category IV</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And then in your database creation, you would access this as:

```
String[] categories = 
    mContext.getResourcees().getStringArray( R.array.categories );

for( String category: categories ) {
    ... insert category here
}
```

That way, you don't have to touch your java code at all, and can add/remove categories from resources only.